# C# how to match textbox string linq

Tags: c#, forms, linq, match

I'm having trouble matching textboxes using linq.
I have to populate a textbox with a collection that I converted from an array.
The conversion looks like this.

```
    List<string> animalList = new List<string>(animals);
```

The list contains items such as "Dog", "Cat", "Snake", "Rat", "Mouse", "Duck"
I can populate the first textbox (there are 3 textboxes, one for the collection, one for a word to be input, and one to display whether or not the input word matches the collection).

I don't know much about Linq.  Please help point me in the right direction.  I've looked all over online, and I can't find an example for something that should be as simple as matching 2 textboxes using Linq.

Comment: TextBox for collection contain all items in the list by separated comma?

Comment: I have them separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as `textbox1.Text == textbox2.Text`

Comment: It should be.  But I need to use Linq to search the collection.

Comment: Here is a list of linq methods that work on enumerates (things you can iterate with a for each loop): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Once you start using those you'll fall in love. If you have any experience with databases you'll have a leg up on understanding them.

Comment: One way to solve your problem would be to keep the collection of strings in the background, and then when a user modifies the text in the textbox (detect this with the TextChanged event) take their input and do `collection.First(s => s == userTextBox.Text)`

Comment: If that returns null there was no match, otherwise you have a match.

Comment: Check out the example section of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank You!  I was able to use this (don't know how to format for code in comments, I'm sorry).  Do you know if this will work for what I'm looking for?  Also, it's returning a match, but only if it's the exact same.  Is there a way I can convert the textboxes ToUpper() or ToLower() so that it returns a case insensitive match?  Anyway, here is the code that got it working:  bool match = nameList.Contains<string>(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = match ? "Yes" : "No";

Comment: you can use `bool match = nameList.Any(x => string.Equals(x, textBox2.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));` so that you it would case insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Linq is the way you want to go here.  `List<T>` has a `contains()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) that should do what you want.  Where is the Linq requirement coming from?

Also, I think you mean a Listbox for the collection (as they're designed to hold multiple items), a textbox for entering new values and then a textbox (or label) to display the result after you test the entered value against the contents of the collection, right?

In your event handler you'll want to use a statement like this:

```
animalList.SingleOrDefault(a => a == textbox1.Text);
```

That assumes that the textbox where the name of your new animal is typed into is named textbox1.

Comment: It's the requirement from the person who gave it to me.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I'll update the answer with an example that should get you going.

Comment: I appreciate it, man.  This was kind of thrown at me, and I don't have any experience with Linq.  But I sure will start learning (since I have to).